Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
I sometimes face this frustrating Node.js issue on Windows:
npm --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v19.9.0

What can I do to fix it?

Answering your own question is perfectly fine, but please format your initial post as a question, and then use the Answer box below to post the answer.

Thanks for your comment i did that @Mathias R. Jessen :D

That looks much better, thank you :)

how to fix :
1 - add nodejs "C:\Program Files\nodejs" in the user and system Environment Variables
2 - try to add new system variable go to Environment Variables--> in system variable section click "New" variable name : nodejs
variable value : path to your nodejs in the program files
example:"C:\Program Files\nodejs"
then click ok --> ok --> ok
3 - if non of the above works try to remove nodejs from every point in your system and install it again , then try to repeat the same things in  1 and 2

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
